# How to save data on parse after login using parse?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parse-platform

I have used parse.com for login and registration, and successfully registration details are begin saved on parse.com, and login works fine too. `But I want to make a form after Login`. In Which , When user login into app, he will see a form to fill up, and again details provided by him should be stored inside parse.com . 
Advance Thanks if great response...

**Logcat**

```
11-10 13:04:05.798    2764-2773/? E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'release' not called
            at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:180)
            at android.drm.DrmManagerClient.<init>(DrmManagerClient.java:258)
            at com.google.ccc.abuse.droidguard.DroidGuard.runNative(Native Method)
            at com.google.ccc.abuse.droidguard.DroidGuard.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.google.android.gms.droidguard.d.f.a(SourceFile:34)
            at com.google.android.gms.droidguard.d.l.a(SourceFile:71)
            at com.google.android.gms.droidguard.d.k.a(SourceFile:92)
            at com.google.android.gms.droidguard.d.k.a(SourceFile:68)
            at com.google.android.gms.droidguard.l.a(SourceFile:249)
            at com.google.android.gms.droidguard.c.t.onTransact(SourceFile:60)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

I did something as shown below, but when user enters his name, it says form error..

**Form.java**

```
public class Form extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables
    Button send;
    String nametxt;
    EditText name;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.formfilluo);

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);


        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);


        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                nametxt = name.getText().toString();


                if (nametxt.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please complete the reservation form",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {


                    ParseObject dataObject = new ParseObject("User");
                    dataObject.put("name", name);
                    //User is classname created on parse.com
                    // name is a column in the class"User"

                    dataObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                // Show a simple Toast message upon successful registration
                                Intent iSuccess = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SubmitSuccess.class);
                                startActivity(iSuccess);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Successfully Reserved your table",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Form Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
                                name.setText("");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="world.yakuza.krishnavanshi.dev15_10_2015"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name="ParseApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginSignupActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Welcome" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Offers" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainForm" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Form" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SubmitSuccess" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[form_layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiTuc.jpg)

What i changed to save data is given below:
[SignUp to SaveData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5uxI.png)

Comment: So you're using the exact same technique for register/login and it works?

Comment: Could you paste your Android.manifest file?

Comment: @AndrewV plz have a look, I uploaded an image `( SignUp to SaveData )` which shows changes I made.

Comment: @penkzhou updated AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Can't you use Parse query for that ?

Comment: as the error says it might be because you are not releasing a certain resource after using it

Comment: and because of that error, it might terminate that action before it sends/receives any data

Comment: @PiyushGupta can we use parsequery to save data on parse.com ? how ?

Comment: Instead of `ParseObject dataObject = new ParseObject("User");`, can you try `ParseUser dataObject = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();`? Since you have already logged in, there should be an instance of User already.

Comment: @Ralphilius i tried ParseUser instead of ParseObject, it shows : ` App has stopped `

Comment: @Ananya In the code, the class is FormFillUp, but in the AndroidManifest.xml it's Form?

Comment: @Ralphilius tried too with Form.java, Still cant get rid of `form error`